# how to use the accelerometer in libgdx what is the specific code

Tags: libgdx

I have a problem using the accelerometer in libgdx because I am new at it and I want to know how to make the accelerometer. So can you please send me the code so I can use it in my game. P.S I am a sixth grader and be very clear when you answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();


        if (accelX < -1){
              //go up
        }


        if (accelY < -1 ){
            //go left
        }

        if (accelX > +1 ){
        /go down
        }

        if (accelY > +1){
            //go right
        }
```

use that code to move something ok?

Answer (score 1):

To use it is very easy!

```
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();
```

You get a value from -10 to 10. 0 Would mean that the device is not tilting at all.

To test is write in your render / update method this to debug your accelerometer movement

```
System.out.println( Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()+" "
    Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY()+" "+
    Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ());
```

Now start your game and look at the logcat while you are tilting your phone!